# Overlapping quinquennial data - How to compare?

Tags: panel-data, method-comparison

I actually do not know if this is the right place to ask, but I hope someone can help me.

I have a dataset that provides the number of newborns in quinquennial periods. For instance, I have the number of babies born between 2003 and 2007, then I have the same number provided for the period 2004-2008 and so on. So these periods are overlapping with each other. The problem is that I need to compare this data with other variables that are provided yearly. The question is, how can I do so? Is there a way for me to transform this quinquennial data to yearly data?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

#My dataset looks something like this:

```
example <- wrapr::build_frame(
   "Period"     , "Country", "Value" |
     "2003-2007", "1"      , 76      |
     "2003-2007", "2"      , 19      |
     "2003-2007", "3"      , 15      |
     "2004-2008", "1"      , 77      |
     "2004-2008", "2"      , 16      |
     "2004-2008", "3"      , 14      |
     "2005-2009", "1"      , 80      |
     "2005-2009", "2"      , 13      |
     "2005-2009", "3"      , 17      |
     "2006-2010", "1"      , 78      |
     "2006-2010", "2"      , 10      |
     "2006-2010", "3"      , 18      )
```

Comment: Could you explain what it means to have *four* values for each time period and country combination?

Comment: Sorry, just realized that when creating the example I used the wrong variable. It's corrected now. For each time period and country combination there is only one value

Answer (score 0):

From what you said, there is no error-free way to decompose your quinquennial data. A possible approach could start from the computation of a linear regression on your quinquennial data to identify the underlying trend. Once you have the trend, you can distribute your quinquennal data equally on 5 points (1 per year) and rescale these values applying the trend found at the previous step.

Best